# Transfer file through text on sockets. [C# and Python]

Tags: c#, python, file

I'm currently working on a project that include file transferring. The way I originally planned it was to read it in python via

```
f = open(filename)
f.read()
```

and write it in C# using the File object interface, and the same from C#, I'm reading it through

```
File.ReadAllText(file)
```

and saving it in python.

It is transferred via sockets.
For some reason, it keeps corrupting the files. Even though the sending is perfectly fine(I checked it a thousand times), the files is read and written properly, so I'm looking for information about how to read a file through text(only text) and not having it corrupted. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Networking(Python):

```
def send(msg, sock):
    msg = msg.__repr__()
    size_of_package = sys.getsizeof(msg)
    package = str(size_of_package)+":"+ msg
    sock.send(package)

def recv(sock):
    try:
        header = sock.recv(2)
        while ":" not in header:
            header += sock.recv(2) 

        size_of_package, separator, message_fragment = header.partition(":")
        message = ""
        while len(message) < int(size_of_package) - len(message_fragment):
            recvsize = int(size_of_package) - len(message_fragment) - len(message)
            if recvsize > 2048:
                recvsize = 2048
            message+=sock.recv(recvsize)
        full_message = message_fragment + message
        return full_message
    except OverflowError:
        return "OverflowError."
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

Networking C#:

```
private void Send(string st)
    {
        int size = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(st);
        string pack = size + ":" + st;
        buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pack);
        connection.Send(buffer);
        MessageBox.Show(buffer.Length.ToString());
    }
    private string Recv()
    {
        try
        {
            buffer = new byte[2];
            connection.Receive(buffer, 2, SocketFlags.Partial);
            string header = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 2);
            while (!header.Contains(":"))
            {
                connection.Receive(buffer, 2, SocketFlags.Partial);
                header += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 2);
            }
            int size = int.Parse(header.Split(':')[0]);
            string mes0 = header.Split(':')[1];
            buffer = new byte[size];
            connection.Receive(buffer, size, SocketFlags.Partial);
            string fullmes = mes0 + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);


            return fullmes;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

File saving (Python)

```
class fileSaver:
    def __init__(self , fileInf):
        self.fileInf = fileInf
        self.file = open(BASE_PATH+fileInf.getPath(), "wb")
        self.file.write(fileInf.getContent())
        self.file.close()
```

where fileInf is an object that contains all the info, including content, etc.

File loading(C#):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
networking.Upload(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('/')+1), basepath, sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Where is your effort? post your code where you are sending and receiving data from sockets.

Comment: Compare the original and corrupted at a byte level,. How they are different should give significant clues about what is not working.

Comment: @Richard The weird part is that I see a small similarity between the file but usually the read file is a few times smaller(not a constant * original size, I checked)